# Setting up LAMP without Internet

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, lamp

For a school project, we have to set up a server with LAMP. However, we cannot connect the server to the Internet during the installation process. We tried using CentOS and putting CentOS .rpm packages on a USB drive. However, there were always dependency issues so we think we have to find another way to install the packages.

What other ways are there to set up LAMP without the Internet?

Comment: Is CentOS mandatory or you can use whichever distro you want?

Comment: Can create a local repo and put that on a USB or network drive and configure the system to use it instead of the internet repos. Then use `yum` to install packages and dependencies. Google `centos local repo` for more information.

Comment: Depending on the connection speed, creating a local repo might take... a while.

Comment: Did you try checking the dependencies and manually download them all, including the LAMP server? You should consider AppServ, which is really lightweight.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try downloading all the CentOS DVD iso's (there's 2 from what I can see) instead of a minimal or network install?

I'm not familiar with the entirety of the CentOS suite but if you install from the full distribution instead of a network or minimal install, all the dependencies ought to be on the discs.

If your connection speed is too slow, this is a great opportunity to support Linux by buying the discs.